# C# Xamarin Invisible Imagebutton's Background

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, alpha, android-imagebutton

I have a very Simple Question, But i did'nt find it from google.

Question: How Can i Set Imagebutton's BackRound invisible or Alpha

What i tried but did'nt work:

```
android:background="Alpha"
```

Comment: "Transparent" is what you're looking for

Comment: Error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  String types not allowed (at 'background' with value 'Transparent')

Comment: Sorry, it was "@android:color/transparent"